Recurisve components select active aelement
I made a recursive component in vue that shows a tree structure.I'm trying to add an active class to the element that is clicked but I can't reset the selection when I click a new element.
This is the father component
<div class="tree-menu-links">
       <ul class="tree-menu-links">
          <tree-menu
          :label="PP.tree.label"
          :nodes="PP.tree.nodes"
          :depth="0"
          :expand-all="expandAll"
          :selected="PP.tree.selected"
          @reset-selection="resetSelection"
      ></tree-menu>
   </ul>
</div>

and this is the Tree-Menu component
<template>
  <li>
    <ul class="tree-ul">
      <div
        @click="toggleChildren"
        :class="{ 'tree-item': true, active: selectedElement }"
      >
        <!-- <div :style="indent" @click="toggleChildren" class="tree-item"></div> -->
        <v-icon
          class="tree-icon"
          v-if="nodes"
          :icon="
            !showChildren && !expandAll
              ? 'mdi-plus-circle-outline'
              : 'mdi-minus-circle-outline'
          "
        ></v-icon>

        <div>
          <span
            @click="selectElement(nodes)"
            class="tree-span"
            :style="[{ color }, showChildren ? { fontWeight: 'bold' } : {}]"
            >{{ label }}</span
          >
        </div>
        <!-- <span
          class="tree-span"
          :style="[{ color }, showChildren ? { fontWeight: 'bold' } : {}]"
          >{{ label }}</span
        > -->
      </div>

      <tree-menu
        v-if="showChildren || expandAll"
        v-for="(node, index) in nodes"
        :index="index"
        :key="node.label"
        :nodes="node.nodes"
        :label="node.label"
        :color="node.color"
        :depth="depth + 1"
        :expand-all="expandAll"
        :selected="node.selected"
        @reset-selection="resetSelection"
      ></tree-menu>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>

<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
  label: String,
  color: String,
  nodes: Array,
  index: Number,
  depth: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  expandAll: Boolean,
  selected: Boolean,
});

const checkedNodes = ref(props.nodes);
const selectedElement = ref(props.selected);

const resetSelection = (nodes) => {
  selectedElement.value = false;
  checkedNodes.value.forEach((node) => {
    node.selected = false;
  });
};

function toggleChildren() {
  showChildren.value = !showChildren.value;
  //selectedElement.value = !selectedElement.value;
  emit("reset-selection");
}

Any idea?
I tried using emit to pass the result of the reset selection method but the previous element is not resetting

Just a suggestion, but you could try using a separate state management library instead of trying to pass props/event-handlers to every subcomponent. You could just keep an id of an active element in shared state you would base your 'selected' value on. The official store library for vuejs is pinia.
